# jquery validation library re-position error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hey guys im using the jquery validation library here http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate my select dropdowns here is my script

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#selfServiceForm").validate({

                rules: {
                    GroupBy1Value: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },

                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertBefore(element.parent());
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
```

this is all copied from their documentation. Instead of displaying it before an element. how can i display it after my h4 tag within a span element so it can sit right next to the h4 tag

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="title">
                <h4><label for="GroupBy1">Group By</label></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <select id="GroupBy1Value" name="GroupBy1Value"><option value=""></select>
                <select id="GroupBy2Value" name="GroupBy2Value"><option value=""></select>
                <select id="GroupBy3Value" name="GroupBy3Value"><option value=""></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

disregard the razor syntax. Thanks for all the help

**UPDATED REMOVED RAZOR SYNTAX AND ADDED RENDERED MARK UP, ALSO DIDNT ADD OPTIONS IN SELECT ELEMENT**

Comment: Only show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup of the `form`, not the server side Razor view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i display it after my `h4` tag within a span element so it can sit right next to the `h4` tag

1. If you want the error within a `span`, then you need to change [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) to `"span"`.

   ```
   errorElement: "span"
   ```
2. Use a combination of jQuery DOM traversal methods to get there...

   ```
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       error.insertAfter(element.parent().prev('.title').find('h4'));
   }
   ```

   [`element.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) - Get the parent of the `element` object

   [`.prev('.title')`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) - Then get the immediately preceding sibling with class `title`.

   [`.find('h4')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) - Then get the descendant that is an `h4`

   [`error.insertAfter(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) - Then insert the `error` object `after` the element matched within.

Comment: thank you sparky, i guess i overlooked that rule, but overall thanks for helping out. This was giving me a headache. thanks again.